# How to display 2mb size image  asp.net image control?

Tags: asp.net, image, asp.net-3.5

I want to display image in my asp.net image control there I am facing a problem because of the image size. If image size is less than 1mb on runtime it will be visible but more than 1mb it will not display. How can I fix this problem?

Code:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; width: 1345px;">
    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="ImgTop" ImageUrl="~/Images/dh_banner.jpg"
        Width="100%" Height="100px" />
</div>
```

Comment: Check in configuration (of IIS and ASP.NET) whether a limit has been put onto a HTTP response size.

Comment: there is now tag like httpruntime in my web.config file, we suppose to specify image maximum length under httpruntime tag.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problems loading images of different size with an ASP.NET `Image` control so I think the issue might be something else unrelated to the actual images.  How are you comparing the two images (the 1MB image and the 2MB image) to determine it is a size issue?

There is nothing wrong in the code you posted that stands out.  Can you reach the image that is not displaying from your web application via a regular URL?  Are both images included in the project in the same directory?  Make sure both images are being used under identical conditions and see if you get the same result.

**EDIT:** If you can put both images in the same location and reference the in the same way and the only difference is size then it is probably your IIS that is not serving up the larger size image.  Try accessing the image directly via your browser like `http://yourURL/Images/dh_banner.jpg` and see if you can see the 1MB+ image.  If you can't see it this way either than IIS is the problem.  If you can see it then it is probably how your referencing the image in your ASP.NET code.

If it is indeed an IIS issue then this link should help you fix the problem:

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits

Comment: yah, i concluded because of i took large size images and i compressed those images after that image size will be 27kb now iam getting those images on runtime but lmb size image is not at all visible at runtime

Comment: Thank you for your response, if browse image through url it is not visible so i checked my iis there i installed request filtering what is prolem can you explain me.

Comment: @Rajkumar Reddy at this point there is not much more I can do to help you.  You need to troubleshoot it and provide more information or re-open a new question as this one is probably complete now that you know it is not specific to the control.

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config file you should adjust the max file size you can render.

Here is the 2 setup I changed or added in the web.config:
Under system.web put :

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="30720" executionTimeout="7200"/>
```

And Under System.webServer put :

```
<security>
   <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="31457280"/>
   </requestFiltering>
</security>
```